# Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

Hello I am new to android dev and admob. I am trying to make a simple test app with a button, a couple pages and admob at the bottom. Everything works fine until I try implementing admob. Here is my code:

HelloAndroid.java:

```
package com.manny.HelloAndroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        //image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HelloPage2.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:src="@drawable/bak_vert_480x800"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/test_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_arrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
     <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="b14be806e9ddf1f"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

hello android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.manny.HelloAndroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloAndroid"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloPage2">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|s    mallestScreenSize"/>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

logcat output:

```
05-09 13:12:00.859: D/dalvikvm(24278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 44% free 3054K/5379K, external 2357K/2773K, paused 94ms
05-09 13:12:00.937: D/dalvikvm(24278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 44% free 3053K/5379K, external 3857K/4816K, paused 31ms
05-09 13:12:01.085: D/AndroidRuntime(24278): Shutting down VM
05-09 13:12:01.085: W/dalvikvm(24278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e560)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manny.HelloAndroid/com.manny.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroid}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:253)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1716)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at com.manny.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroid.onCreate(HelloAndroid.java:17)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    ... 11 more
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.manny.HelloAndroid-2.apk]
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-09 13:12:01.109: E/AndroidRuntime(24278):    ... 20 more
05-09 13:12:11.593: I/Process(24278): Sending signal. PID: 24278 SIG: 9
```

I am using GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-6.0.0. Again I am very new to this and I have tried using examples off multiple sites but the app continues to crash when it hits a page with admob in it. If someone can help me it would be much appreciated. Thank you. If more code is needed let me know.

Comment: It sounds like to me your AdMob SDK jar is not being bundled into your APK. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Have you recently updated your Android Tools to r17 or higher?  If so, you need to create a libs/ folder in your project, and physically put the SDK in the project.  Or, in the Java Build Path, you must Order and Export the SDK jar.

Otherwise, the jar doesn't get included when your apk gets compiled, and all hell breaks loose when you run AdMob code at runtime.

NOTE: This applies to any library your project references.

Comment: omg thank you, I had added it to the external jars but I did not order and export it.

Comment: yah mee too, i created a libs folder and copied and pasted the library and it works fine now. I did not order and export it.

Comment: Sir,can you suggest me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178044/android-admob-is-there-any-violation-to-remove-resources-from-google-play-serv

Comment: Dear Eric, Plz help me fix this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495499/admob-interstitial-fill-rate-is-too-low-10

Answer (score 10):

For me it worked like this.

- close eclipse
- add manually the sdk ad jar file in your project's "libs" folder
- open eclipse
- refresh your project till the sdk jar appears on libs folder
- go to your project's properties > Java Build Path > Library Tab and choose "add Jars" instead of an external one. and select the sdk from the list below.
- go to "Order and Export" tab and select again the SDK
- click ok AND ITS DONE.

Then just add the proper code in the manifest and the xml.

Comment: Restarting eclipse helped me finally after doing all the things.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this, too. The build path didn't seem to work no matter what I did. So I exited Eclipse, created a new libs folder in the workbench package directory. Added the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar to that folder. I DID NOT add the whole SDK, just the jar file. Then restarted Eclipse. I had to refresh the project inspector column to show the changes I made outside of Eclipse. It showed the new libs folder and jar file, but it still didn't work... Then I right clicked on the new libs folder and set it as a SOURCE FOLDER. NOW EVERYTHING WORKS!

Im using Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Android Development Tools   18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

It seems that maybe the tools are ahead of the documentation... or some kind of Eclipse bug.... Very aggravating!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and noticed that ordering the export list is also important.
This is mine, this way it works:

[image]

Comment: I updated from Admob 6.2.1 to 6.3.1 (rev. 10) and I saw the crash `Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView`, which wasn't fixed by simply putting a check-mark next to GoogleAdMobAdsSdk at the bottom of the "Order and Export" List. Thanks for your screenshot ! Moving the AdMobAds SDK to the top of the list worked !

Answer (score 0):

What I did - is working for me now - API Level 17
For admob:
- Add adview  code to your Layout with appropriate ID
- Add Admob manifest code to your project manifest file
- Add an external GoogleAdmobAdsSDK....jar Jar file to your Library (in Properties\Java Build path)
- Check to choose GoogleAdmobAdsSDK....jar in tab Order and Export
- Restart your ADT

DEGUB = WORKING NOW.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio:
 1. Paste the Google AdMob SDK into the libs folder for your project
 2. Add an entry to dependencies section of your build.gradle for the project pointing at the jar.
 3. Rebuild your project

```
dependencies {
...
compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar', '... other entries...')
}
```

Note that compile files takes multiple jar entries. If you already have a compile files entry you can just add to it by separating entries with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The same error appears to me and i solved with few simple steps
You need to remove the appcombat dependency from your project 
for removing right click your project->android->remove app combat and make sure you have selected android 4.2.2 
and then import the google admob jar into your project.