# thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3b1f8)

Tags: android

Ever since I included AdMob into my app everytime I run it and click on a button that goes to a page with Ads on it all I get its "thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3b1f8)"

Main java:

```
    package com.co500.gdsg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameDevStoryGuideActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button co = (Button) findViewById(R.id.combinations);
        co.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.co500.gdsg.COMBINATIONS"));
            }
        });

        Button jb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.jobs);
        jb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.co500.gdsg.JOBS"));
            }
        });

        Button ty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.type);
        ty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.co500.gdsg.TYPE"));
            }
        });

        Button con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.consoles);
        con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.co500.gdsg.CONSOLES"));
            }
        });

        Button gen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genre);
        gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.co500.gdsg.GENRE"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="com.co500.gdsg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity 
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        ></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameDevStoryGuideActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Genre"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.GENRE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Combinations"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.COMBINATIONS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Consoles"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.CONSOLES" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Notgood"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.NOTGOOD" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Hmm"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.HMM" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Notbad"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.NOTBAD" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Creative"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.CREATIVE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Amazing"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.AMAZING" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Jobs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.JOBS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Type"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.co500.gdsg.TYPE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Game Genre Unlocks" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/consoles"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consoles" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/combinations"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Combinations" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Game Type Unlocks" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/jobs"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Jobs" />

</LinearLayout>
```

consoles.xml (similar to the other xmls)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/consoleavail" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="empty for a reason"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:

```
07-13 15:16:13.770: D/dalvikvm(4567): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 2% free 7848K/8007K, paused 14ms
07-13 15:16:13.780: I/dalvikvm-heap(4567): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.377MB for 1769056-byte allocation
07-13 15:16:13.810: D/dalvikvm(4567): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 2% free 9573K/9735K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-13 15:16:13.830: D/AndroidRuntime(4567): Shutting down VM
07-13 15:16:13.830: W/dalvikvm(4567): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3b1f8)
07-13 15:16:13.830: E/AndroidRuntime(4567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 15:16:13.830: E/AndroidRuntime(4567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.co500.gdsg/com.co500.gdsg.Consoles}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
07-13 15:16:13.830: E/AndroidRuntime(4567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-13 15:16:13.830: E/AndroidRuntime(4567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
```

Comment: Did you add correctly the admob lib ?

Comment: Yeah its in the Referenced Libraries

Comment: Did you see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523703/error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview)?

Comment: Yeah I tried it but still no result

Comment: In your properties, make sure you are compiling against at least api13 if it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

you are using this below statement

```
 startActivity(new Intent("com.co500.gdsg.CONSOLES"));
```

Which is causing problem.

use

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityName.this,CONSOLES.class);
```

first param of Intent should be a context and second should be the className.this is a target class

P.S :- it will show error as ActivityName not found, Please replace ActivityName with your Activity Name.

Comment: Your Intent constructor does not exist, I guess you are talking about new Intent(Context, Class)

Comment: When I put that I got an error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" on this and "Syntax error on token "or", invalid AssignmentOperator" on or

Comment: guys.. i written or to let you know either use this or activityName.this,

May be it is not understandable. updated my asnwer

Comment: Either way AdMob is the problem as everything was running fine until I added it

Comment: try Console.class instead of String name

Comment: @Ankit I was saying the constructor Intent(Context, String) does not exist. [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent())

Comment: Yes @CFlex, it is his code i just copied. Now i updated it. THanks for correcting. :)

Comment: the start activity is not the problem, Logcat is saying "XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView"