# admob adview causes crash on android while rotating

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I added the admob adview from xml like this;

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@id/footerContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="..."
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
```

First; there seems to be no problem. But when i change the orientation of the screen a couple of times quickly; the app crashed. I have these errors;

```
1- bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
>   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1785) at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:118) at
>   android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:85) at
>   android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:81) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect...
>
> 2- Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class
>
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error
>   inflating class  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) at
>   com.X.ui.FooterFragment.onCreateView(FooterFragment.java:21) at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:...
>
> 3- Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.x/com.x.ui.HomeActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.X/com.X.ui.HomeActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2953)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygo.

I tried adding it programmatically as described [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals), but nothing changed... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For 1, what SDK version are you using, and what device are you running it on? This may be an emulator specific issue.

2 and 3 are likely due to not linking the AdMob library correctly. See [Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523703/error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview/10525760#10525760).

Comment: hi @Eric, i'm using the latest version (6.2.0). I'm using a real device with android 2.3.7. While changing the orientaion i look at the memory usage, and i see it increases untill it crashes. There must be a memony leak in the adview. I also tested the same thing with the official Soundhound app and it crashed too.