# AdMob add not display Ad in Android App with AndEngine

Tags: android, admob

I have followed all the steps for adding an AdMob Ad into my app from the link at 
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Advertisements-to-Your-Android-Applications-Using-Admob

But when I run my App it does not display the Ad. My app uses AndEngine and hence the target =android-17 as opposed to android-13 specified in the link which causes compilation errors. I added the method onCreateBundle() and wanted to test AdMob. But I get this error in logCat
in my activity_main.xml for  with the message

> "Error inflating class com.google.ads.Adview. I can see that the jar file has been added to the build path.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong. I added the code more than 12 hours back and yet there is no display.

Answer (score 0):

The problems was fixed by by clicking Project->Propoerties->Build Path-> Order & Export and then building. See

[Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523703/error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview)