# Android AdView Fails to Initiate

Tags: android, admob, adview

I recently bought a new MacBook Pro and transferred some project files that were built using Eclipse Juno. The new MacBook Pro had Eclipse Kepler installed. My projects are showing an error in the editor view that states that the google adview class is not initializing, and so the adview is not being shown. I downloaded the admob sdk and copied the jar file into the libs file as directed, so I am not sure what the problem is here. I think that its a directory problem within the project files. Would the directories for the google admob sdk files that came with my project files from the old MacBook Pro be different than what the new install of Eclipse has to work with? I'm still pretty new to this development stuff, so I'd appreciate any help. Thank you! Here'a the error Log:

```
    The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-2)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:184)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:352)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

P.S.

I've looked at some of the other related questions on here, and have had no luck. I believe my problem lies in the directories associated with the project files I transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a build path issue, as it's not able to load json package while showing the layout. Or may be a plugin issue, most probably.

Even though it does show the Adview in the layout, it should work fine when you run the app.

Have a look at these few tips on another similar answer on SO.

[Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523703/error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview)

Comment: After messing around with my build path, I decided to experiment with something. I removed all jar files, and then replaced them.I also added the jar file from each platform (7 to 19) and made my libs folder a source folder. For some reason that I don't understand, this worked! Do you have any insight about why this solved the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Not really. It should have worked in the first place. It's probably a bug in the ADT tools.

Comment: Are you using the Admobs SDK, or the Google Play Services Library?

Comment: I'm using the Admobs SDK. Installed it and the ADT just like the instructions specified, but for some reason it's not working properly. I guess it is just some kind of bug in the package I downloaded. Either way, it works! Hopefully there aren't any issues at runtime.