# Android Google Play Service Not Launching

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google Play service to existing projects after adding the library project does not work. As it gives an error.

```
08-19 12:53:52.863: E/Trace(1977): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-19 12:53:52.883: D/dalvikvm(1977): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 2% free 10809K/11011K, paused 2ms, total 9ms
08-19 12:53:52.883: I/dalvikvm-heap(1977): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.922MB for 2457612-byte allocation
08-19 12:53:52.895: D/dalvikvm(1977): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 13209K/13447K, paused 10ms+0ms, total 12ms
08-19 12:53:52.947: D/AndroidRuntime(1977): Shutting down VM
08-19 12:53:52.947: W/dalvikvm(1977): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62be288)
08-19 12:53:52.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 12:53:52.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iloveyou.lovetester/com.iloveyou.lovetester.LoveTestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #85: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
08-19 12:53:52.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-19 12:53:52.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at
```

[image]

Comment: show your LoveTestActivity and the associated XML file

Comment: Can you post XML file at line 85 (Binary XML file line #85: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView) and related .java class?

Comment: See this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523703/error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview)